# IE8 strange crash: cache?

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8

I've built a JAVA survey web application with 70 questions. All the questions have some html radio buttons to choose the answer. Those questions and answers are dynamically generated to adapt themselves to the user choices path.

After the user click on a radio-button my web application re-generates some HTML dynamically. It seems incredible to me, but when the user click for the 23rd time/item the browser causes IE8 to crash a tab and do a recovery.

I reduced the amount of generated html and this made the user reach a higher item: 40 (and of course a higher number of time my app can generate HTML code without crashing).

This error is absent on other browsers.

The best guess I made is that, after generating a certain amount of HTML, IE8 reach some sort of cache-size-limit and is unable to handle the page.

On my computer, where I have IE8 latest release and IE-web-development tools I get no errors.

Using Visual studio 2005 we found this (Sorry I translated It from my mother tongue) :

mshtml.dll
UnHandled Excpetion 0x3fdf1b8a on iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading on the path 0x00000000.

IE8 version is 8.0.6001.18702

Ho can I debug It?
Can I use JavaScript to reset the cache? 
If yes, could you provide me a snippet of code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOUND!**

It's due to the SmartScreen filter. My code manipulate the DOM adding text by the **`innerHTML`** property. Under certain situations It fires the SmartScreen filter for phishing and malware protection.

[**This**](http://boardreader.com/thread/IE_8_0_6001_18702_Unmanaged_exception_on_syrc__74c15fcd-0d9e-4f09-af97-0f88d3ac423c.html?o=70) says that a lot of users have the same issue.
I will document any progress I have in the next week. I plan to avoid using **`innerHTML`** under IE8 going by the DOM **`appendChild`** properties.